# ffmpeg drawtext filter with zoom in effect

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using draw text filter to display text on video.i need to add zoom in and zoom out filter on text. is there any command for zoom in and zoom out the text on video.

Comment: The fontsize parameter in drawtext can be animated. The hitch is fontsize has to be an integer value, so the rescaling (which will simulate the zoom) will look jerky. Text position will also have to be animated to zoom about the center of the text. The other possibility is the zoompan filter acting on the result of a drawtext output, which is then overlaid on the BG.

Comment: Can you Give me one Example of you have explained above? @Gyan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

One method is to use ASS subtitles with the [animated transform](http://docs.aegisub.org/3.2/ASS_Tags/#%5Ct) tag (`\t`):

```
{\an5\fscx0\fscy0\t(0,500,\fscx100\fscy100)}Text zoom
```

- `\an5` Center text
- `\fscx0` Set font x scale to 0%.
- `\fscy0` Set font y scale to 0%.
- `t(0,500,\fscx100\fscy100)` In 500 milliseconds set `\fscx` and `\fscy` to 100%.

This is easy to do in Aegisub.

Then run your `ffmpeg` command using the [subtitles filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles).

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "subtitles=zoom.ass" output
```

Example ASS file where text will zoom in and then zoom out.

```
[Script Info]
; Script generated by Aegisub 3.2.2
; http://www.aegisub.org/
Title: Default Aegisub file
ScriptType: v4.00+
WrapStyle: 0
ScaledBorderAndShadow: yes
YCbCr Matrix: None

[Aegisub Project Garbage]
Active Line: 1

[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
Style: Default,Arial,20,&H00FFFFFF,&H000000FF,&H00000000,&H00000000,0,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,1,2,2,2,10,10,10,1

[Events]
Format: Layer, Start, End, Style, Name, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Effect, Text
Dialogue: 0,0:00:00.00,0:00:03.00,Default,,0,0,0,,{\fscx0\fscy0\t(0,500,\fscx100\fscy100)}zoom text
Dialogue: 0,0:00:03.00,0:00:04.00,Default,,0,0,0,,{\fscx100\fscy100\t(0,500,\fscx0\fscy0)}zoom text
```

Comment: is there any other way to get the text dynamically using php ?

Comment: @testaccountwizorbit I don't really understand what you are asking. You can integrate this command into a PHP script.

Comment: i mean can i put this text anywhere on the video on screen such like center left or center right or top left top right or anywhere else on video

Comment: @testaccountwizorbit Yes. You can add [`\an`](http://docs.aegisub.org/3.2/ASS_Tags/#\pos) or [`\pos`](http://docs.aegisub.org/3.2/ASS_Tags/#\pos) tags directly to the ASS file, or just set position in Aegisub and have it do it for you, or set it directly in the subtitles filter: `subtitles=subs.ass:force_style='Alignment=5'"` (see `\an` tag for meaning of values). Setting it in subtitles filter will apply declared position to all subs in the file. Using one of the other first two methods will allow you to set it piecemeal per title.

Comment: can i have zoom in and zoom out effect in one ass file for same text at same position but different time?

Comment: @testaccountwizorbit Yes. See example ASS file in answer.

Comment: How to use .ass file in ffmpeg command and where to put in our internal storage?
I already put in internal storage but its not working
"-i", inputPath, "-filter_complex", "subtitles=/storage/emulated/0/project/text.ass", outPutPath
use above command but its not display anything

Comment: @Makvin What is "internal storage"? Show your actual command being executed and the complete log from the ffmpeg command. Use a pastebin site and provide the link in a comment.