# How to add Text with transition effect to video with ffmpeg?

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, effects, ffmpeg-php

I want to **add text in video like subtitles**, i know how to add text to video, now i want to add text with **transition effects like presentation**. How can i do that with using **FFMPEG PHP**. Is there any other possibilities to achieve that? Thanks in advance

Below is example of effect i wan't to achieve

[image: https://78.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_md1hh3mSQq1rntgxe.gif]

Comment: @LordNeckbeard i've updated my question with examples, please check

Comment: Are you using drawtext or subtitles filter? Or will either work for you?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard i have just basic understanding that we can add text to video by using FFMPEG, but i haven't implemented that yet because i want to make sure that how to add effect with text, can you help me with this

Comment: See link above for method using [drawtext](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) filter. Alternative method is to make subtitles file, such as with Aegisub, and use the [subtitles](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) filter in ffmpeg. Refer to the [`\move` tag](http://docs.aegisub.org/3.2/ASS_Tags/). If you want other effects ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50338336/1109017) I recommend using subtitles instead of drawtext.